# Escape apostrophe in Query of Query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, qoq

I'm trying to do this:

```
<cfquery name="GetAccountsAndStocks" dbtype="query">
    Select STOCK, CUST_NUMBER
      From GetExtractionData
     WHERE CUST_NUMBER NOT LIKE  '\''
</cfquery>
```

The `cust_number` is either `'` (for blank) or `'` followed by a 10 character string.

I thought I should escape the `'`, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: (Edit) Can you clarify? What do you mean by "no luck"? What was the result and how did it differ from what you expected? Also, when you say "blank" do you mean the value is an empty string ie "", or that it literally contains the character `'`? Side note, syntax can vary by vendor, so always your dbms with any sql questions.

Comment: It's a coldfusion query of queries; I didn't think to include that because I tagged it (and the tag is the syntax for it)

Comment: No, it is my bad. I only saw the generic "sql" tag, not "qoq". I overlooked the dbtype="query". Not enough coffee ;-)

Comment: It could be partly my fault as I added the `sql` tag. But there isn't a `query of queries` or `coldfusion-qoq` tag (at least, not that I saw).

Comment: @DavidFaber - No worries. I still should have picked up on the dbtype="query".  Added "QoQ" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape a single quote, use `''` (two single quotes), e.g.:

```
WHERE cust_number NOT LIKE ''''
```

However, I'm not too familiar with the use of `NOT LIKE` in query of queries; ordinarily one would use a wildcard (such as `%`):

```
WHERE cust_number NOT LIKE '%''%'
```

In your case you say `cust_number` is a single quote if it's intended to be blank. You would not use `NOT LIKE` for that, but just `<>`:

```
WHERE cust_number <> ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

cfqueryparam solves this problem equally well with q of q and database queries.

Comment: Good call - `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="'" />`